# Meaning of "" in Java Conditional Statement

Tags: java

I'm reading through a Java textbook and it has some examples of the following form:

```
if (true "" false) {
    //do something
}
```

where `true` and `false` are actually some test conditions, but `""` is a literal set of double quotes.
My question is what do the double quotes mean in this context? Is it the same as `&&` or `||`? If so, why not just use the symbols that are familiar?

EXACT EXAMPLE:

```
if (grid [i] [j] != WALL "" grid [i] [j] != CORRIDOR {
    throw new NumberFormatException();
}
```

where WALL and CORRIDOR are defined `public static final byte`

here is snapshot[`Data Structures and the Java Collections Framework Third Edition by William J. Collins published by Wiley ISBN 9780470482674 -page 200`]

---

[image]

---

Comment: `if (true "" false) {`it is not valid statement

Comment: Does the book not explain its examples? (That is not compilable code.)

Comment: This might be a typo. What is the name of the textbook?

Comment: Please give us an exact example (not where it's "like" something).

Comment: @AndersonGreen Data Structures and the Java Collections Framework Third Edition by William J. Collins published by Wiley ISBN 9780470482674

Comment: Can you show the actual code?  You may simply be misreading it.  Or try typing it into your IDE and seeing if it compiles.

Comment: @JonKiparsky pg 200 in the isOK() method and Maze() constructor

Comment: @DavidWallace I'll post a picture, but does anyone know if that can be done on this site

Comment: Like I said, type it into your IDE and see if it compiles.  The code that you've quoted doesn't compile in MY IDE.

Comment: It's probably suppsed to be `&&`.

Comment: I've just seen it. It does say exactly that. It's a typo. It's either meant to be && or ||.

Comment: Yes, but why would you throw a `NumberFormatException` if a byte doesn't have the value you expect?

Comment: And `||` wouldn't be very useful.  If it's anything, it's `&&`.  Also, don't forget to insert a `)` before the `{`.

Comment: @pbabcdefp using || seems to make most sense in the constructor, but && seems more correct in isOK()

 the NumberFormatException has to do with other things going on in the constructor. The class expects the value to be 1 or 0  so anything other than WALL or CORRIDOR should be treated as invalid

Comment: You're right, it's obviously `&&`. I didn't even try to think about it. It's a bizarre book. For some reason `grid[][]` has the modifier `protected`.

Comment: I think the most important conclusion is that you might want to consider getting another book.

Comment: This is probably a weird exercise. You should fill `||` or `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds dummy but you could check on your keyboard, the " button and | button is very near, so the most possible answer is that's a typo of the editor.